# Enforcing object max size and content/mime type within signed upload URLs

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In order to generate expiring upload URLs we are using [Cloud Storage signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs).
Now, we need to restrict the maximum file size (i.e. 32Mb) and also the accepted content-types - only image files will be valid.
Are there any built-in mechanism within GCS which allow us to enforce this upload policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the Content-Type, it is an option part of the string when creating the [Signed URL](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs). Google Cloud Storage will return when HTTP requests are made for the objects.

It's possible to specify a [policy document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument) when preparing a signed POST request, including requirements like expected `content-type` and `content-length-range` with a minimum and maximum size.

For cases where the values supported by a policy document are not enough, you can use [Object Change Notification](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) to implement custom validation on your uploads, including limiting by size. If an upload didn't meet your rules, you could delete it immediately.

Comment: @NachoColoma About bandwith consumption: if I understand the 2017 pricing correctly, the 1TB transfer is "ingress" and it is now free : https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-egress

Comment: @Ripounet You are right about that. Anyway, it's now possible to specify a minimum and maximum size. I just deleted my comment because it's outdated, and updated the response from Brian Dorsey

Comment: @NachoColoma thanks for this edit, this is great. Do you know if a policy document equivalent would be likely for a PUT request? I'm using PUT from mobile app, following this advice from the doc "we strongly recommend using PUT object instead of POST".

Comment: @NachoColoma can you give an example of a policy document working with a PUT? Do you mean it can work alongside a signed url?

Answer (score 2):

The [POST Object](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject) method can be used with an expiring [policy document](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#policydocument) that restricts both the content-length and content-type of the uploaded object.

Comment: can you provide any example for this?